# How to use application.yml file from my sub modules?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

Hi I am working on a spring boot application which contains multiple apps and multiple modules.
Folder structure is like this

```
project
       - apps
         - app1
         - app2
       - modules
         - module1
         - module2
```

each modules have their own resource `application-module{number}.yml` file.

Now I am using these `module1` and `module2` in my app1 which is a spring boot application.

`app1` have `application.yml` file which contains this

```
spring:
    profiles:
      include: >
          module1,
          module2
```

I also added `EnableConfigurationProperties({Module1Config.class, Module2Config.class})` after `@SpringBootApplication` in my application file of `app1`. Still configuration are not getting picked up.

If I am putting those modules config in app1 llike

```
app1
   - resources
        - application.yml
        - application-module1.yml
        - application-module2.yml
```

then it is working. But I want to use those from my modules only.. How can I do that???

Answer (score 1):

Oh I did it somehow...

I added one `application.yml` file in module1 resource folder with content

```
spring:
    profiles:
       include: >
          module1
```

similarly in module2

```
spring:
     profiles:
         include: >
            module2
```

It's working now... thanks to me... :)

Comment: thank you for posting the solution! I have the same issue which is solved by your answer.